# Matching User Data with SID instead of Username?

Tags: c#, .net, security, windows-authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

All the examples I can find for storing/filtering data in Lightswitch end up comparing usernames directly, for example:

```
partial void OrdersForUser_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable query)
{
    // Only show the Orders for the current user
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserName == this.Application.User.Identity.Name);
}
```

This seems like a bad idea to me as usernames can (and do) change.

Is the ASP.NET Membership UserID (a guid) or SID available somewhere to match on?

Comment: Yes, you can get the running user's SID from the code, but does whatever you are querying have a SID available to compare to?

Comment: Well I'd have a table with a `varbinary(85)` key.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Membership UserID from the username, you can use:

```
MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(this.Application.User.Identity.Name);
Guid userGuid = (Guid)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: I took a shot at this; I am hoping to improve my own knowledge of this, so take what I say with a grain of salt and please provide any feedback on how it can be improved. If this does not apply to you, let me know and I will delete the answer.